# Access JSON Object in ajax success

Tags: json, ajax

Somehow I can't find out how to access my json object from ajax call.
In the handler, I'm echoing next id:

```
echo json_encode(array(
   "nextId" => 2
));
```

Then I want to access it with data:

```
$.ajax({
   [...],
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(data) {
       console.log(data)
       console.log(data['responseText'];
       console.log(data['responseText'].nextId);       
       console.log(data['responseText']['nextId']);
   }
});

Result: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"nextId":2}", responseJSON: Object, status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
Result: {"nextId":2}
Result: Undefined    
Result: Undefined
```

I want to get the value of nextId

Comment: As you can see in the log, the value of `data.responseText` is a **string**. Are you using jQuery? jQuery should decode the response automatically for you. It seems strange that you are getting that value as first argument to the success function.

Comment: I think you'll have more luck with `console.log(data['responseJSON'].nextId);` ?

Comment: Yeah that worked @MacPrawn. Submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your data object, I see an object in there called responseJSON... Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
   [...],
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(data) {
       console.log(data)
       console.log(data['responseJSON'];
       console.log(data['responseJSON'].nextId);       
       console.log(data['responseJSON']['nextId']);
   }
});
```

Hope this helps!